# locking down windows 7 lab computers through group policy

Tags: group-policy

I'm kinda new to Windows administration, so please forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about. We have a domain environment that has a mixture of Windows server 2003 and server 2008. I have been administering a Windows server 2003 lab server that controls our labs that have Windows 7 clients.

The problem that I have been having is that students have been installing browser toolbars (conduit seems to be the main culprit) that allow them them to install apps such as bittorrent clients within the toolbar. This also changes the search engine to conduit search. They have been using this to bypass the security policies that were put in place by the last administrator.

They also seem to be able to change the wallpaper, this was not a problem when all the clients were Windows XP.

Anyone know how to solve this problem through group policy or some other method?

Comment: What is a `"Lab Server"`? Is it a Domain Controller? Do you have a separate forest for your labs? What browser are the toolbars being installed on? Please re-read your question and pretend like you're one of us; someone with no idea what your setup is. You need to be a lot clearer with what you are asking.

Comment: First step: Everyone is a limited user.  Second step: [Software Restriction Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This thread might help you.

https://superuser.com/questions/9411/prevent-installation-of-ie-toolbars

In group policy there is also a bunch of things regarding how a person can interact with aspects of the desktops. You can turn off the ability to change background by forcing the one you want. If you have access to group policy that would be ideal, if not you can use the local security policy by running gpedit.msc. Local security policy is more difficult to maintain but if you get it the way you want you shouldn't have to adjust it very often.